# Split string from a date

Tags: php

I want split a string using PHP to get a individual date info.

For example:

```
$date = '08/05/2010';
```

would create the varables

```
$month = '08';

$day = '05';

$year = '2010';
```

Thank you.

Comment: But of course such a trivial question will get a dozen of answers.

Comment: Sorry, I new there was a way to convert it to an array, but couldn't find the function. Thank you Frederico for explode()

Comment: @Chad Whitaker: Please accept correct answers to your questions!

Comment: I guess thank you is like accept :p

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$date = '08/05/2010';
list($month, $day, $year) = explode('/', $date);
```

Answer (score 4):

if that's your example, you could [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it into an array.

$array = explode('/', $date);

Answer (score 2):

`list($month, $day, $year) = explode('/', $date);`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's always in that format, you want [`explode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
<?php

    $date = '08/05/2010';

    $arr = explode("/", $date);

    list($month, $day, $year) = $arr;

    // $month = 08, $day = 05, $year = 2010.

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers posted above would do the trick. You probably also want to check the date conforms to your expected format before you run your function. The [checkdate function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) would be useful for this, or [this snippet](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#89360) is a standalone implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments about using the checkdate function, however that is really for after you split the date apart because you pass in each part (month, day, year) to check.

If you are getting the original date from user input you might want to make sure that you are getting the right format before you separate it out (using list or explode as shown previously.)

I see two options for validity if it is coming from a user: first is to only allow them to select the date, and not freely enter it. The second is to make sure you are getting it in the mm/dd/yyyy format you are expecting. You could perform a [regular expression match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) on it before the separation. The regular expression could be something like /\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}/

Anyway, not really needed if you are sure of your source, but it is always important to think of where your data is coming from and how clean it is.