# How to extract the values of a date in y-m-d format?

Tags: php, regex, string, date-parsing

Let's suppose I have this date: `2016-07-27`. What I want to achieve is:

```
$year = 2016;
$month = 07;
$day = 27;
```

What I have tried:

- `$year = preg_match("/^[^-]*/", "2016-07-27");`
  **It returns**: `1`
- `$month = preg_match("(?<=\-)(.*?)(?=\-)", "2016-07-27");`
  **It returns**: `Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '('`
- `$year = ???`

How can I extract the numbers between the dashes and store them into the variables below as shown above?

Comment: that's because [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) returns 1 if the pattern matches, and 0 if not. Have you searched Google or SO posts with your issue yet?

Comment: [How to get year and month from a date - PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967970/how-to-get-year-and-month-from-a-date-php) **&&** [Split string from a date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3524881/4577762) **&&** [How to split date (08-17-2011) into month, day, year?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7103617/4577762) (Some might not be exact duplicates, but they certainly help) @JohnConde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a string that wont change its format, then you can simply do this:

```
$date = '2016-07-27';
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $date);

echo $year; // 2016
echo $month; // 07
echo $day; // 27
```

However, if the date format changes, then you should use `date_parse` or other `DateTime` methods.

Comment: Nice answer. I'm going to accept it, because it is shorter and preserves the 0 at the beginning as well.

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel - [`date_parse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php) will do all the heavy lifting for you:

```
$parsed = date_parse('2016-07-27');
$year = $parsed['year'];
$month = $parsed['month'];
$day = $parsed['day'];
```

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii-. Missed that one.

Comment: @Mureinik I didn't know this function existed. Thanks for pointing it out.